# D3 Angular - line break in axis label

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/lable-line-break-p1f9hb?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

The x-axis have long labels that I need to split after the second word, so I have a title and sub title

When I'm creating the x-axis I'm calling a function that splits the string up and adds them as separate tspans

```
this.chart.append("g")
    .call(this.x_axis)
    .classed('x-axis', true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")

    .selectAll(".tick text")
    .each(this.insertLinebreak)


private insertLinebreak (d) {

    let labels = d3.select(".x-axis .tick text");
    let words = d;
    labels.text('');

    let index = words.indexOf(' ', words.indexOf( ' ' ) + 1)
    let title = words.substr(0, index)
    let subtitle = words.substr(index + 1)

    let tspantitle = labels.append('tspan').text(title)
    let tspansubtitle = labels.append('tspan').text(subtitle)

    tspantitle
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('dy', '15')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis-title');
    tspansubtitle
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('dy', '16')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis-subtitle');

};
```

My probelm is its adding them in the wrong order and missing one of the titles

What I am doing wrong, is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Can you give the stackblitz URL that would allow us to fork it?

Comment: I have updated the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in `insertLinebreak` is the source of the problem, because it retrieves all the label elements every time you want to process one of them (watch the console in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lable-line-break-rmnef2)):

```
private insertLinebreak(d) {
  let labels = d3.select(".x-axis .tick text"); // <-- This line causes the problem
  ... 
}
```

---

In order to select only the label that you are processing, use `d3.select(this)`:

```
private insertLinebreak(d) {
  let labels = d3.select(this);
  ... 
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lable-line-break-vx5plk) for a demo.

Comment: This is how I have it in my actual app but I get an error - `error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<BaseType>'`. I know this is a different question but I can't replicate it to show the code. The code for my actual app is exactly the same as the stackblitz

Comment: I can only help with the code that is provided in the question and in the stackblitz. As you can see, the forked stackblitz works with the suggested correction.